# implement exact filters by passing multiple data

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question about how to show the exact data in a filter, I am making a filter that passes 5 data to filter it, which I want the first 3 data that I pass to be exact, the problem is that if I pass a data with the value of id 1 It brings me the data that has id: 1-10-11-111 I only want it to bring me the 1.
This is my controller where I do the query

```
public function getProcess(Request $request){
  
   if($request){
            $entity = trim($request->get('entity_id'));
            $process = trim($request->get('process_id'));
            $proveed = trim($request->get('proveed_id'));
            $queryord_compra = trim($request->get('ord_compra')); 
            $querydescrip = trim($request->get('descrpcion'));
            
            $ord_compra =Order_com::where('entity_id','=',$entity )//where('entity_id','LIKE', '%'. $entity  .'%')
                                        ->where('process_id','=',$process)//where('process_id','LIKE', '%'. $process  .'%')
                                        ->where('proveed_id','=',$proveed )//where('proveed_id','LIKE', '%'. $proveed   .'%')
                                        ->where('ord_compra','LIKE', '%'. $queryord_compra .'%')
                                        ->where('descrpcion','LIKE', '%'. $querydescrip .'%')
                                        ->get();
           
    }
    $data = ['ord_compra' => $ord_compra,'proveedores' => $proveedores];
    return view('admin.order_compra,$data);
}
```

I made a query with the first 3 data but when filtering nothing is shown

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dd(\DB::getQueryLog());` on the line right after your query to see what the SQL query is, this might help you investigate the problem.

With what you describe, your approach is correct - however I do see some potential issues.

The main issue I see is you are not doing any server side validation on your request, therefore some of these values can be empty or null, which could explain the lack of results.

You should also do a `dd($request);` to ensure the data being passed to the eloquent model is what you're expecting.